# Maven Webapp Project not recognizing the custom ruleset during build

Tags: eclipse, maven, pmd

I have a Maven WebApp project (Just a HelloWorld Servlet) in Eclipse and running tomcat server. My ultimate aim is to fail the build if the code contains out.print statements. I have defined the maven pmd plugin 2.5 in the pom.xml as below and defined a customized ruleset in a file called sop.xml as below.

But when I right click the project -> Run As -> Maven Build and try to package it, the build is successful and creating the war file. I want the build to fail because the .java code contains the out.print statements.

I am new to Maven and requesting all your kind help on this regard. Thanks.

### Ruleset file(sop.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom ruleset" xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0
http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
<description>This ruleset checks my code for println statements</description>
<rule ref="rulesets/JavaLogging.xml" message="Must handle exceptions">
</rule>
</ruleset>
```

### POM.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                          
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MavenWebGroupId</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenWebArtifactId</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MavenWebName</name>
<description>MavenWebDescription</description>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <targetJdk>${compile.source}</targetJdk>
                <rulesets>
                    <!-- Custom local file system rule set -->
                    <ruleset>c:\rulesets\sop.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
                <linkXref>true</linkXref>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `maven-pmd-plugin` doesn't executed during packaging. To calling this plugin during packaging define it as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
     ...
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>run-pmd</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                 <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note to `<executions>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am getting another error 'Could not find resource 'c:\rulesets\sop.xml'. Although I check that the sop.xml is present in the same location. Should I place it at a different place?

Comment: I was able to rectify this error after I placed the sop.xml inside the src/main/resources folder in the maven project in tomcat itself.

Comment: You also may put `sop.xml` to `src/main/config` directory and reference to it as `${basedir}/src/main/config/sop.xml`. If my answer was helpful to you, so please accept it.